# Dynamically form columns in bootsrap using php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

i want to dynamically display content in 3 bootstrap colums.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<content> 
</div> <---- Problem (should be placed at the very end of the column, 
but the same code should also fill 2nd and 3rd columns)
```

while i fetch the query to mysql. Also i want object to sort in descending order from left to right (id = 51, id = 50, id = 42 (last digit in the object title is id))
I was able to do that, using row_number and row_number%3=0  row_number%3=1 and row_number%3=2 to display 3 columns, but i have to make 3 queries to the database along with 3 blocks of html(which is bad).

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
    @row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS rownum, id,title, description, ...etc
    FROM (
        SELECT @row_number:=0) r, flats ORDER BY id DESC) ranked WHERE rownum%3=1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

But, when i started to implement filters, it caused problems with displaying objects, because not every column had the object i wanted to display, but i had own query for every column.
[Problems with filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFCB3.jpg)

What i want: Dynamically form 3 separate columns with content to use one MYSQL query.
Waiting for your help!
Example of 1 of 3 columns:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<?php
  $zapros = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
    @row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS rownum, id,title, description,type, area,address, square, name, phone, email, price, avito, farpost
    FROM (
        SELECT @row_number:=0) r, flats ORDER BY id DESC) ranked WHERE rownum%3=1 ORDER BY id DESC');
  $zapros->execute();
  $rowsone=$zapros->rowCount();
if($zapros->rowCount() > 0)
  {$tmpCount = 1;

    $count=$zapros->rowCount();
    while($data=$zapros->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      extract($data);


       $number=$data['id'];
                                              $imagestm=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT file FROM flats_images WHERE post_id=:uid LIMIT 1');
                                              $imagestm->bindParam(':uid',$number);
                                              $imagestm->execute();
                                              $imgrow=$imagestm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                              extract($imgrow);?>

<div class="well-lg well-smallborders">
<a href="flat.php?flat_id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
<img src="/mysql/uploads/<?php echo $imgrow['file']; ?>" class="img-responsive title-image center-block" /></a> 
<div class="flat-price center-block"><?php echo $data['price']; ?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-rub" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
<div class="flat-title"><?php echo $data['title'];?> <?php echo $data['id']; ?></div>
<div class="dimmed-text left"><?php echo $data['type']; ?> </div>
<div class="dimmed-text right"><div class="tooltip_my"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span><?php echo $data['area'];?> <span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $data['address']; ?></span></div></div>
<br>
<div class="dimmed-text left"><div class="tooltip_my"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span><?php echo $data['phone'];?><span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $data['name'];?></span></div></div>
<div class="dimmed-text right"> <?php echo $data['square'];?></div>
<table class="flats-table">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="3">
    <button id="collapsar" class="btn btn-info pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hide-me<?php echo $tmpCount;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="btntext">Показать миниатюры</span></button>
    <a href="flat.php?flat_id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info pull-left" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> <span class="btntext">Подробнее ...</span></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="3">
 <div id="hide-me<?php echo $tmpCount;?>" class="collapse"> 
<? 
$imagestm2=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT file FROM flats_images WHERE post_id=:uid');
                                              $imagestm2->bindParam(':uid',$number);
                                              $imagestm2->execute();


for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagestm2->rowCount(); $i++) {
  $imgrow2=$imagestm2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                              extract($imgrow2); ?>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="thumbnail"> <img src="mysql\uploads\<?php echo $imgrow2['file']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  class="img-responsive"/></div>
</div>
    <?

} ?>
</div>
     </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div><?
$tmpCount++;
      }}    
     ?>
     </div>
```

Actual result i want: [Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjCIz.png)

Comment: I think you're thoroughly overcomplicating this. If you were to just get the raw data from your table, what would the query and the result look like? Ignoring the `row_number` stuff

Comment: Normal query looks like this: SELECT id, title, description,type, area, name, phone, email, price FROM flats ORDER BY id DESC all fields are varchar fields exept price which is integer.

Comment: Can you give us, in your question, an example of how the HTML should look when it's complete?

Comment: Added link at the bottom. Also added entire code, that can generate one column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply trying to iterate over your results, generate 3 columns of output, and then also apply filters, maybe through Javascript, which hide some of your elements.  The simplest way I know to do that is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    ... 
    <!-- Bootstrap can manage with only 1 .row -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that solution, but i have button, that shows some thumbnails (bottom left button) And in this case all content is moved to the right, but i want it to move down. That's why i want 3 columns. http://puu.sh/tkQ1z/966fe71963.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do, what i wanted to do, instead i found much easier way to display content: just unite 3 columns in one and put all data there. Ye, it has problems when you open the spoiler, but i think i'll deal with it. Thank you for all your answers.